# How to query SQLite 3 in python that is in a list

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import feedparser
import re
import smtplib
import sqlite3
import time
from datetime import date

db = sqlite3.connect('nvd.db')
c = db.cursor()


def read_from_db():

    read_from_db_list = []
    c.execute('SELECT product_name FROM product')
    for row in c.fetchall():
        read_from_db_list.append(row[0])

    return read_from_db_list


if 'windows' in read_from_db():
    print('i have windows')
```

When I run this I get nothing returned to me. But if in the function `read_from_db()` I add `print(read_from_db_list)` and just paste the function at the bottom of the script it will print me all of the objects in the list.

I just want to be able to query the DB and check if certain keywords are in there.

note: There are 7 'windows' matches in the db.

edit: in the function, I've tried `read_from_db_list.append((row))` and `read_from_db_list.append(row)` aswell

here is what my DB looks like:

https://s8.postimg.cc/u73jx3cet/image.png

Answer (score -1):

Your code won't work because you create a list containing lists by doing `read_from_db_list.append([row])`. It's obvious that the `in` operator won't find the string `windows` inside a list that contains lists. Plus, the result you get from `c.fetchall()` are tuples, thus you have to unfold them first in order to retrieve your columns. Replace

```py
read_from_db_list.append([row])
```

by

```
read_from_db_list.append(row[0])
```

and it'll do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I still get an empty result when I run the code however

Comment: Are you sure, you just updated the line I mentioned and didn't change anything else in that code block in the meantime? **Please also note** the square brackets I removed around `row[0]`. Cause it works for me just fine with that one change :/

Comment: Yep positive! I tried re-pasting the code I initially posted also. I'll update my post to include your modification. I'll also provide a screen shot of the db/table in case I am missing something there.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code :

```
import feedparser
import re
import smtplib
import sqlite3
import time
from datetime import date

db = sqlite3.connect('nvd.db')
c = db.cursor()


def read_from_db():

    read_from_db_list = []
    c.execute('SELECT product_name FROM product')
    for row in c.fetchall():
        read_from_db_list.append([row])

    return read_from_db_list

for data in read_from_db():
    if 'windows' in data[0]:
        print('i have windows')
```

Comment: Hi Bhoomi, thanks for replying. I've tried the code but nothing prints on the screen.

Comment: In loop, data is tuple, use data[0] instead of data in last second line.

Comment: Interesting, this solution is exactly what I posted, just bloated up by a few lines :/ This code just wraps every row in a list, just to unwrap it again outside of `read_from_db()`. When I copy your exact code (which you now changed according to my proposal), it works just fine. There must be something else then that breaks your code.

Comment: @Arno-Nymous before you post your code i have already posted this code.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel No, mine came roughly 30 seconds earlier, look closer at the timestamps and do the math. But that's not what I wanted to say. What I wanted to point out is that's it's quite strange that the OP had no success with my code but with yours, though both do exactly the same.

Comment: @BhoomiPatel And btw, no reason to downvote a working answer just because you wanted to punish me, for whatever reason. That's not very social :/